# Coordinate translation issues

Tags: c#, coordinates, transform

I've been handed a csv file containing a series of coordinates, from which lines should be drawn on top of a bitmap grid; I can get the values out and convert them into ints for the DrawLine function, etc, just fine.

The problem is that these coordinates are basically percentages; x:0.5 and y:0.5 represent dead centre (being 50% of X and 50% of Y) and x:1.0/y:1.0 would be in the top right regardless of the absolute dimensions of what is being plotted on to (in this instance a 1000x1500 bitmap). In addition screen/window coordinates start in the top left which doesn't affect the x-axis but the y-axis needs to be somehow inverted.

So what do I need to do to the coordinates to get them to plot correctly? To be honest I've got the X-axis working fine, it's the Y-axis giving me the problems.

(The window containing the bitmap is 1600x1600, FWIW.)

Comment: How far have you got, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: You are stating what you need to do: 1. Scale the x and y to the 'viewport' you want. 2. Invert the Y coordinate, 3. Translate the origin of your 'vierport'

Answer (score 0):

Well the naive way is to simply calculate the single closest pixel i.e. `round(WIDTH*x)`

But thats bad generally, because some pixels would be left blank, some would be mapped multiple times.

What I'd do is to calculate the percentage of covering per each point - i.e. a point can cover 75% of one pixel, and 25% of it's neighbor and then fill the color of a pixel accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details of what is wrong, I'll take a guess and say that you are calculating your Y value up-side-down.  Try it this way:

```
round(HEIGHT*(1.0-y))
```

Then, give us more details of what you are having trouble with.

Comment: I'm not calculating it at all, it's coming straight out of a file. I use StreamReader to get it out, perform a Regex Replace to get the raw number, then use int.Parse and pass it to the DrawLine function. The problem is, as I stated, that the computer simply doesn't understand that format, windows coordinates start at the top left, not the bottom right, THAT is my problem.

Comment: If you can not understand how what I wrote inverts the y value, I'm not sure I can help you.